# Не задаётся временная директория

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

К проекту на `laravel 5.6` подключён пакет **MPDF**. Создал метод, в нём прописал простой пример с указанием моей временной директории ([как сказано в документации](https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/folders-for-temporary-files.html)):

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');
$mpdf->Output(['tempDir' => '/home/mpdf']);
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> exception: "Mpdf\MpdfException"
>   file: "/var/www/test/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php"
>   line: 17
>   message: "Temporary files directory "/var/www/test/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/../../tmp" is not writable"

Права установил:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему сия либа ругается? Почему не указывается временная директория?

> UPD прописал:

```
chmod 775 /var/www/test/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp
chown doox911:www-data /var/www/test/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp
```

Но теперь либа ругается на неверные параметры.

Comment: Даже в примере документации то что вы пытаетесь сделать передаётся в конструктор класса, вы же это в `output()` всунуть пытаетесь...

Comment: @InDevX, сам только заметил) Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Необходимо установить права **775** на директории `vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp` и на вашу выбранную временную директорию в данном случае — `/home/mpdf/`.
2. Необходимо установить пользователя/группу `chown doox911:www-data` на директории `vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp` и на вашу выбранную временную директорию в данном случае — `/home/mpdf/`.
3. Передать в конструктор массив параметров, в данном случае массив с одним элементом: `$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => '/home/mpdf']);`